# Max-heap implementation with List

Tags: java, heap

I am trying to create max-heap for practice.

Are there any bugs?
Are there ways that I can improve the code quality?

```
public class MaxHeap <E extends Comparable<? super E>>{
  List<E> list;

  public MaxHeap(E[] array){
    this(Arrays.asList(array));
  }
  public MaxHeap(List<E> list){
    if(list == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("list cannot be null");
    this.list = new ArrayList<E>(list);
    buildHeap();
  }

  public void buildHeap(){
    for(int i=lastParent(); i >= 0; i--)
      maxHeapify(i);
  }

  private void maxHeapify(int parent){
    if(isParent(parent)){
      //assume left child is bigger for now
      int biggerChild = 2 * parent + 1;
      int rightChild = biggerChild+1;
      if(rightChild < size() && compare(rightChild, biggerChild) > 0)
        biggerChild = rightChild;

      if(compare(biggerChild, parent) > 0){
        swap(biggerChild, parent);
        maxHeapify(biggerChild);
      }
    }
  }

  private int compare(int fir, int sec){
    return list.get(fir).compareTo(list.get(sec));
  }

  public boolean add(E item){
    if(item == null)
      return false;

    list.add(item);
    int child = last();
    int parent = getParent(child);

    while(isParent(parent)){
      if(compare(parent, child) < 0){
        swap(parent, child);
        child = parent;
        parent = getParent(parent);
      }
      else
        break;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private void swap(int left, int right){
    Collections.swap(list, left, right);
  }

  public int size(){
    return list.size();
  }

  public E remove(){
    if(isEmpty())
      return null;

    swap(0, last());
    E max = list.remove(last());
    maxHeapify(0);
    return max;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty(){
    return size() == 0;
  }

  private int last(){
    return size() - 1;
  }

  private int getParent(int child){
    if(index == 0)
      return -1;
    else
      return (child-1)/2;
  }

  private boolean isParent(int index){
    return index >= 0 && index <= lastParent();
  }

  private int lastParent(){
    return size()/2 - 1;
  }

  public String toString(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int lineCounter = 0;
    int lineMax = 1;
    for(E item : list){
      builder.append(item);
      builder.append(" ");
      lineCounter++;
      if(lineCounter >= lineMax){
        builder.append("\n");
        lineCounter = 0;
        lineMax++;
      }
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work as intended?

Comment: @Jamal It works as far as I can tell.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, Xin. While I understand wanting to check for unforeseen bugs, please keep in mind that bug fixes/error handling would qualify your question as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few smaller issues:

- Why expose `buildHeap()` when every other public method, including the constructors, already leaves you with a perfectly sorted heap?
- Why does the `add()` method contain sorting logic? This would usually be placed in an `increment()` method.
- An `increment()` method is missing.
- Your `add()` method did not copy the element. Your heap is therefore vulnerable to side effects where any of the elements you have a reference on, did get modified in the outside world. Either warn, watch, encapsulate or make immutable.
- Comments? At least your constructors and public methods should be documented, denoting which side effects are to be expected.
- There is no interface to get the sorted list back.
- The `toString()` method returns the internal order of the heap. Nice for debugging, but not what you would expect. You would expect it to return elements in lexicographical order.
- Please don't use it in production. Your basic `MaxHeap` has significantly worse runtime characteristics than the default Fibonacci Heap.
- There is a `getParent()` helper, but you have omitted such helpers for `getLeft()` and `getRight()`, even though you are using the corresponding expressions multiple times.